# A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse on my mac

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

[image]

I have already installed and set java home path and still it is showing this error.

[image]

I have set the java home to this location.
but sitll not able to open scala ide for eclipse on my mac

Comment: Java 17 or higher is required to run recent versions of Eclipse (according to your screenshot you have Java 8). It is recommended to use the Java that is shipped as part of Eclipse. It is unclear how you run into this error. Which IDE package of which version did you install on which way (please tell the download link and if you have used the Eclipse Installer, please also tell what you have chosen in the installer)?

Comment: As a side note: the last commit to the Scala IDE codebase was 7 years ago (https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-ide). You might want to evaluate the option of using a different IDE which enjoys more active support (both IntelliJ IDEA and Visual Studio Code are popular options lately).